# How to get the name of the WebElement variable name in another class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to pass the webElement name to another class for Webdriver operations.I am using the pagefactory model.

I want to print the name of the webelement variable as well in another class.

The below is the code I have.

Class A:

```
Class A{

     @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[text()='Example_23']")
     public WebElement exampleTab;
}
```

Class B:

```
class B{

      public static void Click(WebElement objName) throws Exception
      {
            objName.click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on"+ objName);
      }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
Clicked on exampleTab
```

Actual Output:

```
Clicked on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using below code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

 class A {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[text()='Example_23']")
    public WebElement exampleTab;

    public void initElements(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }

}

public class B {


    public static void main(String r[]) {
        A a = new A();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                   "D:\\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\\playground\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver-2.35.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        a.initElements(driver);  // instantiating class A elements

        driver.navigate().to("url");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Click(a.exampleTab);

    }

    public static void Click(WebElement  objName) throws Exception {
        objName.click();

        System.out.println("Clicked on" + objName);
    }
}
```